# Rails 3 Autocomplete solution with primary_key support

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I've been looking around for a Rails 3 form autocomplete solution. I ran into the auto_complete plugin, but it doesn't have support for assigning a hidden primary key so that a textual response can be used in the form. I'm also looking for something that can is able return a concatenated string in its view, e.g. the firstname and lastname of a user.

Does anyone have any suggestions for a plugin that has this functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this one, if I remember correctly, there is an option that would allow that:
http://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete